# use of "of" or "from" when it comes to years

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct in this case?

In the “Subdue” series of/from 2008, he photographed the daily life of urban centers.

(The "Subdue" series is a series of photographs that was created in 2008.)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I’d use ***from*** if it’s was just informational.  I’d use ***of*** if it was restrictive. I.e., if there were other “Subdue” series produced in other years.